# Need help on a MySQL search query

Tags: mysql

How to search a substring of a varchar column in a table ?

```
SELECT * FROM ch_products 
WHERE cat_id REGEXP '^[2]|,$' AND cat_id REGEXP '^,|[2]$'
```

Comment: What you want to search just mention

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, cat_id varchar(250) NOT NULL, sub_cat_id varchar(250) NOT NULL, status int(11) NOT NULL,created_at datetime NOT NULL,updated_at datetime NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;INSERT INTO ch_products (id, cat_id, sub_cat_id, status, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, '1,2', '16,17','0','0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), (2,'5,11', '18,6', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');I want to search all product having cat id '1'@Sadikhasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM ch_products
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',cat_id);
```

Check [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

Comment: Yes @Sadikhasan You are correct and my issue now solved 90%. If you don't mind Is there any function for array of items. This function works for only one variable. I need for a array of variable. Like $array=array('1','2,'3'); SELECT *
FROM ch_products
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($array,cat_id); something like this

Answer (score 0):

easy.

```
WHERE cat_id LIKE "%|,";
```

Will return  :

```
"abc|,"
"de|,"
"f|,"
```

and ignore :

```
"abc|"
"abc|,d"
"|abc,"
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but in my coloumn I have data as (1,2),(1,12),(1,23) I need to search all records having data '2' Please do guide

Comment: please copy paste your column definition here, this is not clear . How can I figure out after reading ur comment if your table is has two columsn INT/INT, and when you say (1,2), is it a line with two columns? OR is it a only VARCHAR field filled up with "(1,2)". If you want an answer, you better make an effort so we can understand what your problem is...

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products`(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `cat_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  `sub_cat_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;INSERT INTO `ch_products` (`id`, `cat_id`, `sub_cat_id`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '1,2', '16,17','0','0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2,'5,11', '18,6', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');I want to search all product having cat id '1'